# Tracking Execution Time of test cases in jenkins

Tags: selenium, jenkins

Before every release selenium test cases are need to run in jenkins, now i need to track execution time comparison of this build and previous build. Is there any way to store the execution time of each test case in Data Base, So we can easily compare the time..

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there isn't. If you use JUnit you could add listener to the start and end events of a test case and save it anywhere in any form you want. I save the start/end time in a database for post analysis.

Do a Google with JUnit + Listener, here is one of the results:

http://howtodoinjava.com/2012/12/12/how-to-add-listner-in-junit-testcases/